# Sending broadcast event to pusher server using console command

Tags: javascript, events, laravel-5, pusher

I am trying to do something to run tests on sending laravel events using custom console commands.

```
Artisan::command('event:send', function () {
        event(new \MarketPlex\Events\ClientAction([ 'id' => 4, 'name' => 'MyEvent' ]));
        $this->comment(Inspiring::quote());
})->describe('throws an event');
```

My event,

```
class ClientAction implements ShouldBroadcast
{ 
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

/**
* The name of the queue on which to place the event.
 *
 * @var string
*/
public $broadcastQueue = 'client-action';

/**
* Information about the request created by user action (Must be public, otherwise laravel                   can't serialize).
*
* @var string
*/
public $request;

/**
* Create a new event instance.
*
* @return void
*/
    public function __construct(array $request)
    {
        //
        $this->request = $request;
}
}
```

It does not send anything to pusher server. I checked all keys.

```
php artisan event:send
```

Answer (score 0):

Are events working otherwise?

If not, what version of the Pusher library are you using? If you're using 3.0, try a 2.x version.

Comment: ~2.0. but if I use trigger() from Pusher it sends the message to server. But If I use event() helper method it does not send.

Comment: I'm running laravel 5.4 and using Pusher server ~2.6. Still the same.

Comment: Hi, it's difficult to help without seeing all the code - so instead I'll recommend a read of this tutorial. If you can't get this to work, let me know. https://blog.pusher.com/writing-realtime-apps-with-laravel-5-and-pusher/

Comment: I just found the changes I made in .env file. But I need answers if you could help me to find out why it did not work. I have set QUEUE_DRIVER=database in .env file. When I used 'sync' value it sent the message to pusher server! If you have any findings why it works let me know. Now problem solved and event() call send the message :) . Still looking for answers why 'database' did not work.